# Lock One Desktop Icon

Tags: mate, lock, desktop-icons

On Ubuntu Mate 18.04, how might I lock just **one** of my desktop icons,
so it will not be moved. when I "Organize Desktop by Name.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a [feature](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet) of the [GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Design) [(tour)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Tour) used as the Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.  A search of 256 [Extensions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions) presented by a search there on *lock an icon* found none which offers that capability.

I also looked in the [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks?action=show&redirect=Apps%2FGnomeTweakTool) AKA [GNOME Tweak Tool](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/gnome-tweak-tool-renamed-gnome-tweaks) ([more](https://linuxhint.com/best-gnome-tweaks-gnome-tweak-tool/)) [(and more)](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) [(still more)](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Themes-on-Ubuntu-with-Gnome-Tweak-Tool)  which did not have that feature.